# Creating an object in an Array

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object inside an array. Is this code OK?

```
this.bullets.splice(0, 0, new Component(this.y - 3, this.x + (this.width/2), 2, 2, "bullet"));
```

Comment: try it and test it. and have a look to the console [F12].

Answer (score 1):

That's not creating the object inside an array, it's creating the object in an expression, the result of which is fed into a function, which then puts it in the array.

That's fine, perfectly normal, no different from any other expression used as part of a function call.

---

Side note: `.splice(0, 0, x)` (inserting an item at index 0, shuffling any others already in the array down) is slightly more idiomatically written `.unshift(x)`. Nothing wrong with the `splice`, just flagging up the alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays in javascript are 0-based index arrays, meaning you can only have numerical keys. A better way to achieve what you want would be to use another javascript object using object notation ( so `this.bullets = {};` ). You can then mix both numerical and string literals for the keys.

Comment: 1. What is it in the OP's question that makes you think they don't want to use an array? 2. *"...meaning you can only have numerical keys..."* is incorrect. In fact, *technically*, normal arrays never have numerical keys, because normal arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), and property names are strings (except when they're Symbols). And you can have properties on normal arrays that aren't all-digits. `var a= []; a.foo = "bar";` is perfectly valid (and occasionally useful). *(not my dv)*

Comment: A javascript array is indeed an object (or rather everything is in javascript), so yes you can do var a = []; a.foo = "bar" etc. Yes you are correct, you can mix values within javascript arrays (I was confused with another language, apologies).

Comment: Well, *almost* anything is... :-) Some things (number, string, boolean primitives, ...) just get promoted to objects briefly when necessary.